# Yii2 302 Redirect jQuery AJAX request, redirecting entire page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have an action:

```
public function actionAjaxLoadBasketSmall() {
    $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    return $this->renderPartial('@app/views/basket/_small');
}
```

Some JavaScript

```
function loadBasketSmall() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/basket/ajax-load-basket-small",
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#basketSmall').addClass('loading');
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            $("#basketSmall").replaceWith(data.responseText);
        }

    });
}
```

Called from this function for example:

```
function handleProductTileButton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = $(this);
    $('#basketSmall').addClass('loading');
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/basket/ajax-add-product",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
            productId: input.data('product-id'),
            quantity: 1,
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            input.addClass('loading');
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            $('.top-bar .search-results').html(data.responseText);
            input.removeClass('loading');
            loadBasketSmall();
        }

    });
}
```

Whenever the Ajax call is complete the entire page gets redirected to `/basket/ajax-load-basket-small`

These are the response headers. Note the 302 response code.
[image: Headers]

Comment: A redirect in response to an AJAX request _can not_ “redirect the entire page”. That redirect is in response to a background request, so it will be handled in the background as well. Only your AJAX request itself can be affected by such a redirect. If you see the “entire page” change location, then that must be something else.

Comment: It only happens when the JavaScript function is called after the request has been made.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Show us what you are calling when and where.

Comment: It's quite simple. All I need to do is call `loadBasketSmall()` in the console to make it happen

Comment: Well then all you need to do is stop doing that. Wow, that was easy. (And if that is not the response you were hoping for - then give us a _proper_ problem description already …)

Comment: Ah, problem then is when I call it in a different function I get the exact same problem. I updated the description. Funny thing is, when I remove the `loadBasketSmall()` call in the callback in `/basket/ajax-add-product` call the entire page gets redirected to `/basket/ajax-add-product` instead.

Comment: I think the culprate is the X-Redirect header, but I'm baffled why the Ajax call is effected by it. I'm also not sure why the server is responding with a redirect.

Comment: According to https://developer.yoast.com/x-redirect-by-header/ the `X-Redirect` header should contain an identifier that says where the actual redirect originated; this is just a proposal, but it looks like the Yii people might have picked it up? So in that case, this looks to me like that is simply the originating URL, the one that was originally requested, and during processing of that the redirect was issued. (Would still not explain how this manages to redirect your frontend though, because as said - a redirect received in response to a background AJAX request, “stays” in the background.)

Comment: Your initial URL is just `http://locogames/basket/…`, the redirect one is `http://locogames/nl/basket/…` - so a language prefix seems to have been inserted here, due to some sort of automatic language detection & redirection? So I guess you would either have to make your AJAX request against the URL that includes the language specifier already; or disable that automatism for AJAX requests …? (Not sure which one would make more sense; if the AJAX request could return any error messages that would be passed on the the frontend, then probably the first option?)

Comment: Ah the language switch must be the culprate! I was staring at this so much I didn't see that any more.

Answer (score 0):

So it was down to the language detection that was making the server send redirect responses.

To solve this I added this code to my base controller class

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();
    $this->initJsLang();
}

public static function jsDefineLang() {
    return "const LANG = '" . \Yii::$app->language ."';";
}

protected function initJsLang() {
    $this->getView()->registerJs(static::jsDefineLang(), \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD);
}
```

And updated my JavaScript accordingly:

```
function handleProductTileButton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = $(this);
    $('#basketSmall').addClass('loading');
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/" + LANG + "/basket/ajax-add-product",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
            productId: input.data('product-id'),
            quantity: 1,
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            input.addClass('loading');
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            $('.top-bar .search-results').html(data.responseText);
            input.removeClass('loading');
            loadBasketSmall();
        }

    });
}

function loadBasketSmall() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/" + LANG + "/basket/ajax-load-basket-small",
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#basketSmall').addClass('loading');
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            $("#basketSmall").replaceWith(data.responseText);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: why do you have all those functions inside the controller the `LANG` can be defined inside the view why two functions just to initialize a `const` inside a controller? apart from all that if you still need to do it you should add it inside the `beforeAction` rather than init as you need that const to be defined only when a view is loaded in that controller,

Comment: So it globally registers on all my front-end pages. I could do it in before, but init is just as good in my opinion. The reason for seperate functions is so I can override the function that defines the LANG const if need be in a controller.

Comment: its not the same otherwise the `beforeAction` should'nt have been there. If you look into the lifecycle of the request the `init` is called before the action is even created and `beforeAction` is called **after** creating the action but **before** running it. and you can still keep your frontend and server-side code separate if you go for.

Comment: **1)** an `assetBundle` class and inject the variable to the head of the document. **2)** or simply add it to your layout file inside the `<head>` tag. I dont find a reasonable reason to hide that `const` initialization there in the controller where no one other than you knows where it is. and any other developer will keep pulling his hairs if you left the job and handed over the project to someone else

Comment: I have several layout files. I don't want the same code in each of them. The before function would also do the job. I guess it might be tidier. And it's not hidden. It's in an abstraction class that all the front end controllers extend from. assetBundles are for registring files. I'm not going to make a seperate PHP script render a js file and then include it though an asset bundle.

Comment: I never said to create a separate file, you can use the `init()` method of your `AssetBundle` class like `public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $view = Yii::$app->controller->view;
        $language = Yii::$app->language;

        $js = <<<JS
        const LANG="{$language}";
JS;
        $view->registerJs($js, $view::POS_HEAD);
    }` simple as that

Answer (score 0):

So final solution after Muhammad's suggestion

LanguageAsset.php

```
<?php

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Language application asset bundle.
 */
class LanguageAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        $view = \Yii::$app->controller->view;
        $language = \Yii::$app->language;
        $js = "const LANG='{$language}';";
        $view->registerJs($js, $view::POS_HEAD);
    }
}
```

In my layout files I added:

```
use frontend\assets\LanguageAsset;

LanguageAsset::register($this);
```